# apache serf code samples for async client rest api

Tags: c, apache, rest, http

I am trying to use apache serf for doing async client rest api calls in 'C'
I was unable to find any code examples of using serf library  (http://serf.apache.org/) for async rest api. If anyone has any info, please let me know.
Thanks